# Spring Roo RooEntity and RooJpaActiveRecord

Tags: spring-security, http-status-code-404, spring-roo, status

I am a novice with Spring.

I am looking to resolve conflicts between `@RooEntity` and `@RooJpaActiveRecord`. I have used the typicalsecurity addon to an existing project which used more recent versions of Roo (`@RooJpaActiveRecord`). I was wondering if there's a workaround or a specific way to address this issue. I am not able to run the project on the internal web browser. I receive the HTTP Status 404 error.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

@RooEntity is no longer the annotation that you have to use.

Replace it with @RooJpaActiveRecord and run the Roo shell again.

Regarding the web project, the annotations belongs to the spring-roo-annotations.jar (or something like that) that maven puts in your WEB-INF/lib folder when deploying the war application.

You need to have the appropriate jar dependency (I mean, the correct version) depending on the annotation that you have in your code.

In order to see more explanation, maybe you can provide your server stack trace.